# Querying multi-element semi-structured data (json) with Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I can't query properly a semi-structured that is multi-leveled (json) data with Snowflake SQL.
Could you please assist in commenting what is incorrect, data that I am parsing or my FLATTEN syntax?
How to write a correct syntax? Many thanks!
My query is:

```
WITH a AS ( 
SELECT PARSE_JSON('[ 
             {
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312312,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name1",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "ABC",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-15 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312435,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name2",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "Winsows",
"os_version": "n/a" ,
"country" : "AC",
"latitude": 16.35,
"longitude": 31.45,
},
"type_of_conversion": "purchase"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-30 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441554433,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name1",
"campaign_channel": "channel3",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "AB",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-02-28 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312312,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name2",
"campaign_channel": "channel3",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": "9",
"country" : "ABC",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-30 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312435,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name3",
"campaign_channel": "channel4",
"meta":{
"app_name": "Winsows",
"os_version": "n/a",
"country" : "AC",
"latitude": 16.35,
"longitude": 31.45,
},
"type_of_conversion": "purchase"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-03-01 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312355,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name9",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "Linux",
"os_version": "n/a",
"country" : "DE",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "purchase"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-06 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312355,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name9",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "Linux",
"os_version": "n/a",
"country" : "DE",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registration"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441554433,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name6",
"campaign_channel": "channel5",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "AB",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312312,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name1",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "ABC",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312312,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name1",
"campaign_channel": "channel1",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "ABC",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}
,
{
"name": "conversion_event",
"created_at" : "2020-06-04 00:00:00",
"uuid" : 12314512441312312,
"campaign_name": "campaign_name3",
"campaign_channel": "channel2",
"meta":{
"app_name": "iOS",
"os_version": 11,
"country" : "ABC",
"latitude": 12.12,
"longitude": 12.12,
},
"type_of_conversion": "registrations"
}

]')::variant as var)
            
            
            SELECT var:name::string AS "name", meta.value:country::string AS "country", var:uuid::int AS "uuid",
            var:type_of_conversion::string AS "type_of_conversion",  var:campaign_name::string AS "campaign_name",
             meta.value:app_name::string AS "app_name"
                       FROM a
, LATERAL FLATTEN (var:meta) AS meta ;
```

Comment: Your question should include a **minimal** reproducible example. This JSON is not a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

the Actual issue is with your data , not with your code .. In JSON data, you are using multple json obect data as single line .So it would be giving   **Error parsing JSON: more than one document in the input**  . So Snowflake recommend to process data before transforming it. [[Check This]](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#supported-file-formats)

Else you can try by taking one json object out of it .